# Read and then write .pcm files using Java

Tags: java, android

How can I read and then write `.pcm` files using Java on Android, which I just recorded using the microphone at different frequencies?

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
File fileForSaving = new File(Environment.
                    getExternalStorageDirectory(),recordings/" + name + ".pcm"); 
File file = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.pcm");
int sampleFreq = (Integer)freqset[SELECTED_INDEX];
```

I want to save the file to fileForSaving with different frequency rates.

Comment: can some one tell me plzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
       AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
       sampleFreq,
       AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
       AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
       bufferSizeInBytes,
       AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

Comment: here the sampleFreq is changing accordingly

Comment: also i want to make changes to the track like entering the echo sound to this recorded track